# What does predict() in combination with prcomp() do? (R)

Tags: r, pca, predictive-models, cart

I have a small data set with 40 patients (20 positive and 20 negative on some disease), where for each patient gene expressions of 40 cytokines are measured. The goal is to be able to predict status of disease and reduce dimensions simultaneously. I am trying to perform PCA on part of my data and subsequently use the results to correctly diagnose the rest of the data with 0 or 1 respectively (using CART-algorithm, which is not included in the example below).

The whole algorithm works fine - however, I do not really understand what is happening in `predict()` in the last line of the example below. The result is obviously the predicted PC-score for each individual in `pred.data`. But what are these predictions based on? `prin.comp`, as the object returned by `prcomp` has many elements, and to be honest, I don't understand all of them.
And even more important to me: are these predictions meaningful and useful for my purposes (i.e. using them as `newdata` in a subsequent prediction with CART) at all?

```
library(caret)
dat <- cbind(c(rep(0,20), rep(1,20)), data.frame(replicate(40,rnorm(40,10,3))))
colnames(dat)[1] <- "Diagnosis"
train_partitions <- createDataPartition(dat$Diagnosis, times = 1, p = 0.75,list = TRUE, groups = min(5,length(dat$Diagnosis)))
sampled <- as.numeric(unlist(train_partitions[1]))
# choose 30 cases for training and 10 for prediction
train.datasets[[1]] <- dat[c(sampled),]
pred.datasets[[1]] <- dat[-c(sampled),]
# run PCA on training data
prin.comp <- prcomp(train.datasets[[1]][,-1])
predictions <- predict(prin.comp, newdata = pred.datasets[[1]][-1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCA's central output is the rotation matrix $\mathbf{W}$.  This is a $p\times p$ matrix, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a $N\times p$ matrix of data.

$\mathbf{W}$ contrains information on how to map the original data to their equivalent coordinates on the rotated space.  If the new coordinates are $\mathbf{Z}$, then the transformation is
$$
\mathbf{Z = XW}
$$

Say you've got a new dataset $\mathbf{\tilde{X}}$ and you want to make it comparable to $\mathbf{Z}$.  You'd do

$$
\mathbf{\tilde{Z} = \tilde{X}W}
$$
That is what `predict.prcomp` is doing.

Comment: Thank you! So, assuming that the rotation matrix **W** is actually capturing some true relationship between the variables and that the new data contains new measurements of the same variables, it makes sense to apply **W** on the new data? (if I don't want to run another PCA on the new data)

Comment: Be careful. PCA is not an estimator, and the rotation matrix is a deterministic function of the input data. Likewise the rotation matrix on a prediction set is different from that of the test set. Running a separate PCA on the test set would yield a different rotation matrix. In that sense, "predict" is a misnomer. You're not predicting anything, but rather performing identical transformations to the training and test set.